Local access by private IP to an ASP.NET Core application deployed in IIS 10
I'm trying to deploy my application in IIS 10. Access to app should be by private IP 192.168.....
In the section Edit Bindings I specified following settings:
Type: http; ip: 192.168....; port: 80
I enabled the predefined inbound rule "WWW Services (HTTP)"
When I try to open the application I get "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET".
The URL where I received the error: http://192.168.0.78:80.
What could I have forgotten to configure?

Can you specify your AppPool status? Also check the IIS Logs and the Application Logs under the Windows Event Viewer -> left panel  go to Windows Logs -> Application

@mrSoh , status:working. WEV app log: Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/app_example' started process '9224' successfully and is listening on port '21364' (without errors)

What’s the URL when you saw that error?

Please learn how to format URL as code and then edit the question to include it (or paste a clear screen shot). Otherwise, no one can understand what you meant.

@LexLi, thx for the note, I corrected it in the question.

The edits look good, but the situation can be difficult to troubleshoot. IIS bindings can be impacted by many things like the reserved URLs, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/https-binding#reserved-urls So, experiments are needed to dig further.

Do you get any other error messages besides ERR_CONNECTION_RESET? you can check the console or Event Viewer for related error messages.

@samwu, if specify port 80 for another application, then it works fine (also deployed in IIS)

the "another application" is the backend, and the client side does not run

Since the client side does not run, there should be relevant error messages in the console. You can use the developer tools F12 to view it.

@samwu, yesterday I deleted the application in IIS and all its files from the directory and reinstalled everything again. After this, the application began to open on port 80. Today I decided to repeat the same thing and now I get an error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Maybe it's some kind of Windows server service that is blocking the launch?

But when you specify HTTPS and port 443 in the bindings, everything is fine. Could it be true that some service is using the port?

You can check if port 80 is occupied. run the netstat -a command from the command prompt.
